# process dynamic keys with multipart file uploads

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using below API and input , multipart/form request is consumed but for all files, key is static "files" due to `RequestPart("files"`) however key for all String is dynamic because of `Map<String,String>`.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/xyz", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploads(@RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] outputFiles, @RequestParam Map<String, String> keyValues {
...
}

files - file_1_name
files - file_2_name
files - file_3_name
key1  - value1
key2  - value2
```

However API as below does not work as expected. Needed to provide dynamic keys for each File uploaded and also number of total files to be uploaded is unknown, so used a `Map<String, MultipartFile`> instead of `MultipartFile[]`. It still expects static key "outputFiles" for each file uploaded.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/xyz", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploads(@RequestPart Map<String, MultipartFile> outputFiles, @RequestParam Map<String, String> keyValues {
...
}

Input
======
file_1_name - file_1_any_name
file_2_name - file_2_any_name
file_3_name - file_3_any_name
key1  - value1
key2  - value2
```

Can we support dynamic keys like file_name_1, file_name_2 (shown above) for file uploads like a `Map<String, MultipartFile>` using spring boot / spring mvc similar to `Map<String,String>` counterpart ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accepting `MultipartHttpServletRequest request` as argument to controller allows dynamic keys for multipart/form file uploads as well.

```
request.getParameterMap()
request.getFileMap()
```